# Jquery dynamic form plugin, trying to rename field labels as I add them

Tags: jquery, plugins, dynamic-forms

I'm currently using the jquery dynamic form plugin to add form fields. http://sroucheray.org/blog/jquery-dynamic-form/

My challenge is trying to rename the field labels as they are added/cloned:

For example:

Phone Field

Phone Field 2

Phone Field 3

If anyone has experience with this plugin, I would definitely appreciate the assistance. Thanks!

Comment: can we see the generated HTML from using the plugin?

Comment: @Chad, sure thing, I've added it to my original post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the for attribute of the labels created are in the format `phone#` where `#` is the 0 based index,you could do something like this:

```
var i = 0;
var $label = $('label[for="phone' + i + '"]');
do
{
   var txt = 'Phone Field';
   if(i > 0)
      txt += ' ' + i;
   $label.text(txt);

   i++;
   $label = $('label[for="phone' + i + '"]');
} while($label.length);
```

Working jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YTnmy/1/)

**Edit:** In response to David's comment:

One way is to hook when a new clone is added, keeping a count of how many are added (for use in the text). Then you simply rename the added label:

```
var numLabels = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#duplicate").dynamicForm("#plus", "#minus", { //options
        limit: 3,
        afterClone: function(clone) {
            numLabels++;
            var txt = 'Phone Field ' + numLabels;
            $('label', clone).text(txt);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @ DavidJ I needed to increment `i` before reselecting, I changed that and posted a working example.

Comment: @David, thanks for your hard work! trying to figure out how to add this to my jquery snippet above.

Comment: @Chad, Thank you. It doesn't seem to be working, trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: @David can you share the link to your site using this, or create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) for us to play with. Also when you are responding to someone you use @Person, since you are talking to me @Chad is appropriate (@David means you are talking to yourself)

Comment: @Chad, okay, thank you for your patience chad. please find a link to js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/thbgQ/4/

Comment: @David Sorry david, I was wrong about how the clone was inserted into the DOM after cloning, the code in my answer has been modified and now works, also here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thbgQ/23/

Comment: Thank you very much! that works great. One last thing -if I wanted to start the numbering over again after a field is deleted and re-added, do you know how that would be done? For example, right now if i add 2 fields I get Phone Field 1, Phone Field 2. If I delete those and re-add them I get Phone Field 3, Phone field 4 and so on

Comment: @David Sure basically just hook when there is one taken away then reduce the count of the `numLabels` variable, jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/thbgQ/30/

Comment: Thanks for all your help Chad, very much appreciated.

Comment: @David of course, and welcome to stackoverflow hope you enjoy your stay.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method of jQuery...If you need help implementing it, let me know.

Comment: Thank you Guy, love the name. I'm not the speediest with JS, how could I use this to change the label names? I've added my plugin JS to my original post. Thanks so much for the assistance.